# Loading external <Div></Div> to Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb.net, iframe

In my project am using a master page named as `master.aspx` in particular page i need to include another page into the current page, so that i use `<iframe>` to achieve this. while passing the `url` to the `iframe` the master page will also load inside the `<iframe>` how can i avoid such loading of master page inside the iframe?

i can't avoid master page in the page which i called, is it possible to call particular `<Div>` or `<content template>` in iframe?

Comment: am able to transfer the URL but don't have an idea about passing div, that's why am asking here

Comment: Master pages in .Net have an extention of .Master not .aspx .... they have content place holder while .aspx pages that use the master would have corresponding content... See www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp

Answer (score 0):

seems you are using asp.net, maybe you can try to edit the first row in .aspx page, try to add the following code to the page which you don't want to show the master page.

**Theme="" StyleSheetTheme=""**

==== **Update** ====

if you want to hide it in iframe only, you should pass a parameter in url like ?theme=none

then handle it in the Page_load Function in .aspx.cs as follow:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 if(Request["theme"] == "none"){
  Page.Theme = "";
  Page.StyleSheetTheme = "";
 }
}
```

Comment: in which session? in frame i don't want to include master page but i need the masterpage when access it directly